# Can't declare dynamic 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I've stuck on a problem - I can't declare 2D arrays in C++ using integers, written by user.

This code works fine-

```
cin>>m>>n;
int *array;
array=new int[m*n];
```

But I can't make this work -

```
cin>>m>>n;
int *array;
array=new int[m][n];
```

Any ideas how i can bypass it?
P.S. the error : cannot convert 'int (*)[2]' to 'int*' in assignment.

Comment: You're not trying to *declare* a dynamic array (which is actually illegal in C++, all arrays must be fixed size). You're trying to *allocate* a dynamic array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
cin>>m>>n;
int *array;
array=new int[m][n];
```

to

```
cin>>m>>n;
int **array;
array=new int * [m];

for ( int i = 0; i < m; i++ ) array[i] = new int[n];
```

Comment: Do not forget to delete all allocated pointers.

Comment: Do not forget to _explain_ your answer instead of harmfully dumping code on those who do not understand it.

Comment: This isn't a multidimensional array; it's an array of pointers to 1D arrays.  See [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/936687) - apparently C++11 does allow `new int [nrows][CONSTANT];`.  Compilers that support variable-length arrays as an extension can at least cast raw memory to runtime-variable sized 2D arrays as well.

Comment: @PeterCordes This array=new int * [m]; is not a variable length array,  Your comment does not make sense. It seems you are overqualified.:)

Comment: My point was that C++ can't dynamically allocate proper 2D arrays the same way C99 allows (*[Freaky way of allocating two-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36794202)*), except maybe  with C++ extensions.  Giving up and doing inefficient allocation of each row separately is not a good alternative.  If you insist on an array of pointers, PaulMcKenzie's answer on [how to create a contiguous 2d array in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21943621) shows how to do that with two `new`s, one big array for all the `int` data, and one for pointers into it.

Comment: @PeterCordes And where is there in my answer a variable length array allocated? As for your ptoposal then it is opinion based.

Comment: I never said your answer allocates a VLA.  I said that if an implementation supports VLAs, that allows a C-like way to avoid this bad data structure. But there are other ways that avoid the inefficiency while still being portable ISO C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
typedef int RowType[n];
RowType *array = new RowType[m];

doStuffWith(array[y][x]);
```

Or, even shorter (but harder to remember):

```
int (*array)[n] = new (int[m][n]);
```

---

Edit:

There is a catch in C++ that array sizes must be constant for the `new` operator, so you can only do this if `n` is `const`. This is not a problem in C (and the reason I forgot about this), so the following works even if n and m are not const:

```
RowType *array = (RowType*)malloc(m * sizeof(RowType));
```

Of course, you can work around this restriction in C++ by doing this, which works even if both `m` and `n` are dynamic:

```
RowType *array = (RowType*)new int[m * n];
```

The `typedef` free version would be this:

```
int (*array)[n] = (int (*)[n])new int[m *n];
```

Comment: No you cannot ;)
If anything then n must be constant, i belive this is not a case here.

Comment: To be able to do it like this n must be constatant, and it isn't in this case.

Comment: @Bartek You are right, there is a catch in C++. Not nice. C doesn't have such *interesting* restrictions...

Comment: @Bartek Found a way to work around this C++ restriction without resorting to `malloc()` :-)

Comment: C doesn't have this problem because C doesn't have `new` keyword ;) so since you are doing malloc anyway, then it's moving responsibility to lower level functions. Beside sizeof type is calculated in the runtime so typedef which is not used in `new` keyword can be passed to sizeof() function without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I suggest you should use std::vector to avoid memory allocation / deallocation issues.

In case you want an array implementation, then you can declare array as a pointer to pointer to int.

```
cin >> m >> n;
int** array = new int* [m];
for ( int I = 0; I < m; I++ ) {
  array[I] = new int[n];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about vectors.

Answer (score 0):

`array` is `int *` and you try to assign `int **`... change array to `int**`.

2D array is actually array of arrays, so you need pointer to pointer.

Comment: Well, arrays are not pointers, they only *decay* to pointers when used. Thus an array declared as `int array[m][n]` is *not* a pointer to pointer, but one consecutive slab of m arrays of length n. There is no pointer array involved.

Comment: @cmaster array is not a pointer, but the variable `array` in the question is very pointer. Please read again, i just said that he **need** pointer to pointer!

Comment: No, you cannot have a pointer to pointer pointing to arrays of arrays. Neither the types nor the element layouts are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can only use `new` to allocate 1D arrays. In fact, 2D arrays are also 1D arrays, where, in most systems, all rows are simply concatenated. That is called a row-major memory layout.

You can emulate 2D arrays with a 1D array. The index conversion is:

`index1 = y * m + x`

This also has much better performance than creating one array per row, as recommended in the "duplicate" link or in other answers.

Comment: "you can only use new to allocate 1D arrays" is not correct, you can allocate arrays of any type, including arrays of arrays, which is nothing else than multidimensional arrays. Take a look at my answer, if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Domi said (but *not* `index1=y*m+x` but rather `index1=x*n+y` to emulate your desired notation):

```
int *array = new int [m*n];

int get (int x, int y) // emulates array[x][y] for array[m][n]
{
    return array[x*n+y];
}
```

However, I think the real 2-dimensional allocation (as Vlad from Moscow showed you) is slower in creation (and needs a bit more memory), but quicker in accessing. Cause `array[x*n+y] == *(array+x*n+y)`, wether `array[x][y] == *(*(array+x)+y)`, so you have one multiplication less, but one dereferenciation more, in sum *I think* it's quicker.

You could also create a class:

```
class array2d
{
private:
    int *data;
    int mm, nn;
public:
    array2d (int m, int n)
    {
        mm = m;
        nn = n;
        data = new int [m*n];       
    }
    ~array2d ()
    {
        delete[] data;
    }
    int *operator[] (int x)
    {
        return (data+x*nn);
    }
};
```

With it you can use

```
array2d arr(10,10);
arr[5][7] = 1;
```