# how to create a contiguous 2d array in c++?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, new-operator

I want to create a function that returns a contiguous 2D array in C++.

It is not a problem to create the array using the command:

```
 int (*v)[cols] = new (int[rows][cols]);
```

However, I am not sure how to return this array as a general type for a function. The function is:

```
  NOT_SURE_WHAT_TYPE create_array(int rows, int cols)
  {
        int (*v)[cols] = new (int[rows][cols]);
        return v;
  }
```

I tried double*[] and double** and both don't work. I wouldn't want to use double*, since I want to access this array from outside as a 2D array.

Related question: [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Comment: "NOT_SURE_WHAT_TYPE" in C++ that would be `vector<vector<int> >` ;-)

Comment: An array is not the same as dynamically allocated memory

Comment: The only way to create a contiguous "2d" array is as an array of arrays.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Its what I would use as well, but alas it doesn't meet the requirements of the question and return a memory backdrop of the structure as *contiguous*.

Comment: In general, if your function returns a pointer to array of `N` `T`s, it looks like: `T (*func())[N] { /* ... */ }`. However, you can't do that in this situation, because the array size depends on an argument to the function.

Comment: `std::vector` is what you want (or maybe `std::aray`).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want to create an array where the data is contiguous and you don't want a 1-dimensional array (i.e. you want to use the `[][]` syntax), then the following should work.  It creates an array of pointers, and each pointer points to a position into a pool of memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

template <typename T>
T** create2DArray(unsigned nrows, unsigned ncols, const T& val = T())
{
   if (nrows == 0)
        throw std::invalid_argument("number of rows is 0");
   if (ncols == 0)
        throw std::invalid_argument("number of columns is 0");
   T** ptr = nullptr;
   T* pool = nullptr;
   try
   {
       ptr = new T*[nrows];  // allocate pointers (can throw here)
       pool = new T[nrows*ncols];  // allocate pool (can throw here)
       T* startpool = pool;  // Remember the start of the pool
 
       // now point the row pointers to the appropriate positions in
       // the memory pool
       for (unsigned i = 0; i < nrows; ++i, pool += ncols )
           ptr[i] = pool;

       // Initialize pool
       std::fill(startpool, startpool + nrows*ncols, val);
       return ptr;
   }
   catch (std::bad_alloc& ex)
   {
       delete [] ptr; // either this is nullptr or it was allocated
       throw ex;  // memory allocation error
   }
}

template <typename T>
void delete2DArray(T** arr)
{
   delete [] arr[0];  // remove the pool
   delete [] arr;     // remove the pointers
}

int main()
{
   try 
   { 
      double **dPtr = create2DArray<double>(10,10);
      dPtr[0][0] = 10;  // for example
      delete2DArray(dPtr);  // free the memory
   }
   catch(std::bad_alloc& ex)
   {
      std::cout << "Could not allocate array";
   }
}
```

Note that only 2 allocations are done.  Not only is this more efficient due to the lesser amounts of allocations done, we now have a better chance of doing a rollback of the allocated memory if a memory allocation fails, unlike the "traditional" way of allocating a 2D array in non-contiguous memory:

```
// The "traditional" non-contiguous allocation of a 2D array (assume N x M)
T** ptr;
ptr = new T*[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
   ptr[i] = new T [M]; // <<-- What happens if new[] throws at some iteration?
```

If `new[]` throws an exception somewhere during the operation of the `for` loop, you have to roll back all of the successful calls to `new[]` that happened previously -- that requires more code and adds complexity.

Note how you deallocate the memory in the contiguous version -- just two calls to `delete[]` when allocated contiguously instead of a loop calling `delete[]` for each row.

---

Also, since the data is in contiguous memory, algorithms, functions, etc. that assume that the data is in contiguous memory, just like a one-dimensional array, can now be used by specifying the start and end range for the M*N matrix:

`[&array[0][0], &array[M-1][N])`

For example:

`std::sort(&myArray[0][0], &myArray[M-1][N]);`

will sort the entire matrix in ascending order, starting from index `[0][0]` up until the last index `[M-1][N-1]`.

You can improve on the design by making this a true class instead of having allocation / deallocation as 2 separate functions.

---

Edit:  The class is not RAII-like, just as the comment says.  I leave that as an exercise for the reader.  One thing missing from the code above is the check that nRows and nCols are > 0 when creating such an array.

Edit 2: Added a `try-catch` to ensure a proper roll back of the memory allocation is done if a `std::bad_alloc` exception is thrown attempting to allocate memory.

---

Edit: For a 3 dimensional array example of code similar to the above [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068410/allocating-a-large-memory-block-in-c/52069368#52069368).  Included is code to roll back allocations if the allocation fails.

---

Edit: Rudimentary RAII class added:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Array2D
{
    T** data_ptr;
    unsigned m_rows;
    unsigned m_cols;

    T** create2DArray(unsigned nrows, unsigned ncols, const T& val = T())
    {
        T** ptr = nullptr;
        T* pool = nullptr;
        try
        {
            ptr = new T*[nrows];  // allocate pointers (can throw here)
            pool = new T[nrows*ncols];  // allocate pool (can throw here)
            T* startpool = pool;  // Remember the start of the pool

            // now point the row pointers to the appropriate positions in
            // the memory pool
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < nrows; ++i, pool += ncols )
                ptr[i] = pool;

            // Initialize pool
            std::fill(startpool, startpool + nrows*ncols, val);       
            return ptr;     
        }
        catch (std::bad_alloc& ex)
        {
            delete[] ptr; // either this is nullptr or it was allocated
            throw ex;  // memory allocation error
        }
    }

    void deleteAllData() noexcept
    {
        if (data_ptr)
        {
            delete[] data_ptr[0];  // remove the pool
            delete[] data_ptr;     // remove the pointers
            data_ptr = nullptr;  
        }
    }

    public:
        typedef T value_type;
        T** data() {
            return data_ptr;
        }

        unsigned get_rows() const {
            return m_rows;
        }

        unsigned get_cols() const {
            return m_cols;
        }

        Array2D() : data_ptr(nullptr), m_rows(0), m_cols(0) {}
        Array2D(unsigned rows, unsigned cols, const T& val = T())
        {
            if (rows == 0)
                throw std::invalid_argument("number of rows is 0");
            if (cols == 0)
                throw std::invalid_argument("number of columns is 0");
            data_ptr = create2DArray(rows, cols, val);
            m_rows = rows;
            m_cols = cols;
        }

        ~Array2D()
        {
            deleteAllData();
        }

        Array2D(const Array2D& rhs) : m_rows(rhs.m_rows), m_cols(rhs.m_cols)
        {
            data_ptr = create2DArray(m_rows, m_cols);
            std::copy(&rhs.data_ptr[0][0], &rhs.data_ptr[m_rows-1][m_cols], &data_ptr[0][0]);
        }

        Array2D(Array2D&& rhs) noexcept
        {
            data_ptr = rhs.data_ptr;
            m_rows = rhs.m_rows;
            m_cols = rhs.m_cols;
            rhs.data_ptr = nullptr;
        }

        Array2D& operator=(Array2D&& rhs) noexcept
        {
            if (&rhs != this)
            {
                deleteAllData();
                swap(rhs, *this);
            }
            return *this;
        }

        void swap(Array2D& left, Array2D& right) noexcept
        {
            std::swap(left.data_ptr, right.data_ptr);
            std::swap(left.m_cols, right.m_cols);
            std::swap(left.m_rows, right.m_rows);
        }

        Array2D& operator = (Array2D rhs)
        {
            swap(*this, rhs);
            return *this;
        }

        T* operator[](unsigned row)
        {
            return data_ptr[row];
        }

        const T* operator[](unsigned row) const
        {
            return data_ptr[row];
        }

        void create(unsigned rows, unsigned cols, const T& val = T())
        {
            *this = Array2D(rows, cols, val);
        }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Array2D<double> dPtr(10, 10);
        std::cout << dPtr[0][0] << " " << dPtr[1][1] << "\n";
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: Inventive. Not very RAII-like, but does the job.

Comment: Is this what `std::vector` does behind the scene's or would this be much faster?

Comment: Also, I am just wondering, would a better solution to be `T* arr = new T[row*col]` and then rather than making each row point to a block of memory, make the `[]` operator do some math to determine what location in memory it is? (I know this is sort of what is done, but doing this would only require 1 allocation and 1 delete, except accessing elements will be slower)

Comment: The answer given here is to provide a better way of starting of with a `T**` and creating a 2D array.   Using a `T*` is not the goal of the answer given.  Of course, a `T*` or a `std::vector<T>` would be much better, but again, sometimes when a `T**` has to be used, there are far better ways to build a 2D array from it than the traditional approach of allocating `n` buffers in a loop.

Answer (score 10):

Since you're using C++ and not C, I would recommend to use one vector instead of messing around with new/delete.

You can define one contiguous block of memory like this:

```
std::vector<int> my_matrix(rows*cols);
```

And now you access this vector in a 2d-array-like way with the formula i*n + j, with i being the row index, j the column index and n the length of a row:

```
my_matrix[i*n + j];
```

That's the same as accessing a 2d array with array[i][j]. But now you have the advantage of one contiguous block of memory, you don't need to bother about new/delete and you can easily share and return this vector object with functions.

Answer (score 8):

Unless the size of the two dimensions is known at compile time, your don't have much choice: allocate a single `rows*cols` array of `int`s, and roll your own 2D indexing with integer multiplication and addition. Wrapping this in a class can produce a nice-looking syntax for accessing array elements with square bracket operator. Since your array is 2D, you will need to use proxy (AKA "surrogate") objects for the first level of data access.

Here is a small sample code that uses `std::vector<T>` for maintaining a contiguous memory region in dynamic memory:

```
template<class T>
class Array2D {
    vector<T> data;
    size_t cols;
public:
    // This is the surrogate object for the second-level indexing
    template <class U>
    class Array2DIndexer {
        size_t offset;
        vector<U> &data;
    public:
        Array2DIndexer(size_t o, vector<U> &dt) : offset(o), data(dt) {}
        // Second-level indexing is done in this function
        T& operator[](size_t index) {
            return data[offset+index];
        }
    };
    Array2D(size_t r, size_t c) : data (r*c), cols(c) {}
    // First-level indexing is done in this function.
    Array2DIndexer<T> operator[](size_t index) {
        return Array2DIndexer<T>(index*cols, data);
    }
};
```

You can now use `Array2D<int>` as if it were a built-in C++ array:

```
Array2D<int> a2d(10, 20);
for (int r = 0 ; r != 10 ; r++) {
    for (int c = 0 ; c != 20 ; c++) {
        a2d[r][c] = r+2*c+1;
    }
}
```

[Running demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/npmySQ).

Comment: +1 I sometimes ponder how many engineers on any given day eventually think about this problem, try to solve it, then come to the realization that is this answer.

Comment: division/modulo is unnecesary. You pass i,j through operator() and linearise to the index.

Comment: @DieterLücking Because it is C++ syntax for accessing an array, as opposed to C++ syntax for calling a function.

Comment: operator() is the classical semantic for multi-index access. An array is a function somehow anyway.

Comment: @JoelFalcou "An array is a function somehow anyway" Surely, you're not serious about that, right? As far as the "classical semantic" goes, the fact that it is widely used does not make it less unnatural.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Why do you insist on "classical semantic" - it has no benefit here, besides cumbersome indirection.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight well an array is an object you feed two integers to get a value. Hence ti can be seen as (int x int) -> int function. The nice thign with () is that it scales properly with arbitrary dimension number and don't require spurrious wrapper.

Answer (score 6):

handling raw memory ressources is often icky. Best shot is a simple wrapper as :

```
struct array2D : private std::vector<int>
{
  typedef  std::vector<int> base_type;

  array2D() : base_type(), height_(0), width_(0) {}
  array2D(std::size_t h, std::size_t w) : base_type(h*w), height_(h), width_(w);

  int operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) const 
  { 
     return base_type::operator[](i+j*height_); 
  }

  int& operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) 
  { 
     return base_type::operator[](i+j*height_); 
  }

  std::size_t rows() const { return height_; }
  std::size_t cols() const { return width_; }

  private:
  std::size_t height_, width_;
}
```

private inheritance let you grab all the goodies from vector, just add your 2D constructor. Ressources management is free as vector ctor/dtor will do their magic. Obviously, the i+h*j can be changed to whateever storage order you want.

vector< vector< int > > is 2D but won't be contiguous in memory.

Your function then become :

```
array2D create_array(int rows, int cols)
{
  return array2D(cols,rows);
}
```

EDIT:

You can also retrieve other vector interface parts like begin/end or size with the usign clause to make the private inherited member functions public again.

Comment: Besides private inheritance (the array2D could have a member std::vector) the right thing when rows and/or cols is not changing +1

Comment: i just have the habit to priv.inherit ressources class like this. But yeah member is as good. As for rows/cols begins modifiable, i can add a simple resize(h,w) member function.

Answer (score 6):

None of the ways of defining a 2D dynamic array in standard C++ are entirely satisfactory in my opinion.

You end up having to roll your own solutions. Luckily there is already a solution in Boost. [boost::multi_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html):

```
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"

template<typename T>
boost::multi_array<T, 2> create_array(int rows, int cols) {
  auto dims = boost::extents[rows][cols];
  return boost::multi_array<T, 2>(dims);
}

int main() {
  auto array = create_array<int>(4, 3);
  array[3][2] = 0;
}
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gLgoFLyEnK688PhE).

Answer (score 1):

The "Rudimentary RAll" class provided by PaulMcKenzie is an excellent solution. In my use of it I did find a memory leak which is fixed in the version shown below.

The memory leak was due to an issue with
`Array2D& operator=(Array2D&& rhs) noexcept`.

The statement `rhs.m_dataPtr = nullPtr` needed to be removed in order to allow the rhs destructor to delete the original data (pool and pointers) swapped from lhs.

Here is the corrected code for the "Rudimentary RAll" class provided by PaulMcKenzie

```
template <typename T>
class Array2D
{
    T** data_ptr;
    unsigned m_rows;
    unsigned m_cols;

    T** create2DArray(unsigned nrows, unsigned ncols, const T& val = T())
    {
        T** ptr = nullptr;
        T* pool = nullptr;
        try
        {
            ptr = new T*[nrows];  // allocate pointers (can throw here)
            pool = new T[nrows*ncols]{ val };  // allocate pool (can throw here)

            // now point the row pointers to the appropriate positions in
            // the memory pool
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < nrows; ++i, pool += ncols)
                ptr[i] = pool;

            // Done.
            return ptr;
        }
        catch (std::bad_alloc& ex)
        {
            delete[] ptr; // either this is nullptr or it was allocated
            throw ex;  // memory allocation error
        }
    }

public:
    typedef T value_type;
    T** data() {
        return data_ptr;
    }

    unsigned get_rows() const {
        return m_rows;
    }

    unsigned get_cols() const {
        return m_cols;
    }

    Array2D() : data_ptr(nullptr), m_rows(0), m_cols(0) {}
    Array2D(unsigned rows, unsigned cols, const T& val = T())
    {
        if (rows == 0)
            throw std::invalid_argument("number of rows is 0");
        if (cols == 0)
            throw std::invalid_argument("number of columns is 0");
        data_ptr = create2DArray(rows, cols, val);
        m_rows = rows;
        m_cols = cols;
    }

    ~Array2D()
    {
        if (data_ptr)
        {
            delete[] data_ptr[0];  // remove the pool
            delete[] data_ptr;     // remove the pointers
        }
    }

    Array2D(const Array2D& rhs) : m_rows(rhs.m_rows), m_cols(rhs.m_cols)
    {
        data_ptr = create2DArray(m_rows, m_cols);
        std::copy(&rhs.data_ptr[0][0], &rhs.data_ptr[m_rows-1][m_cols], &data_ptr[0][0]);
    }

    Array2D(Array2D&& rhs) noexcept
    {
        data_ptr = rhs.data_ptr;
        m_rows = rhs.m_rows;
        m_cols = rhs.m_cols;
        rhs.data_ptr = nullptr;
    }

    Array2D& operator=(Array2D&& rhs) noexcept
    {
        if (&rhs != this)
        {
            swap(rhs, *this);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    void swap(Array2D& left, Array2D& right)
    {
        std::swap(left.data_ptr, right.data_ptr);
        std::swap(left.m_cols, right.m_cols);
        std::swap(left.m_rows, right.m_rows);
    }

    Array2D& operator = (const Array2D& rhs)
    {
        if (&rhs != this)
        {
            Array2D temp(rhs);
            swap(*this, temp);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    T* operator[](unsigned row)
    {
        return data_ptr[row];
    }

    const T* operator[](unsigned row) const
    {
        return data_ptr[row];
    }

    void create(unsigned rows, unsigned cols, const T& val = T())
    {
        *this = Array2D(rows, cols, val);
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Array2D<double> dPtr(10, 10);
        std::cout << dPtr[0][0] << " " << a2[0][0] << "\n";
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write a simple class to wrap a 1-dim array. Then you can implement a 2-dim array with operator() overloading for getting values and deconstruct func for release the memory. Code as below:

```
#include <assert.h>

template <typename T>
class Array_2D
{
private:
    T *data_inside;
public:
    int size[2];
    Array_2D(int row, int column);
    ~Array_2D();

    // 
    T operator()(int index1, int index2){
        return data_inside[get_index(index1, index2)];
    }

    int get_index(int index1, int index2){
        if(index1>=0 and index1<size[0] and index2>=0 and index2<=size[1]){
            return index1*size[0] + index2;
        }else{
            assert("wrong index for array!" == "True");
        }
    }

};

template <typename T>
Array_2D<T>::Array_2D(int row, int column)
{
    size[0] = row;
    size[1] = column;
    data_inside = new T[row*column];
}

template <typename T>
Array_2D<T>::~Array_2D()
{
    // 使用析构函数，自动释放资源
    delete[] data_inside;
}
```