# How to malloc array 2d in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have this array:

```
float (*probability)[4];
```

This is 2D array but i don't know the number of first [], this can be calculate in some function after and in that function I don't know how to `malloc()` this array.

My code is like this:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    float (*probability)[4];
    some_function_to_malloc(&probability);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `float (*probability)[4]` is not a 2D array.   It is a pointer to a 1D array containing four elements.   They are different things.

Comment: thanks, but how do I malloc it ?, and can it be extract with something like probability[0][4] ?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36794202/5399734

Comment: sun qingyao, it very helpful, thanks you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `float (*probability)[4]` is not a 2D array.  It is a pointer to a 1D array containing four `float`.    They are different things.

Second, an idiom to use `malloc()` without introducing unintended type errors is

```
  probability = malloc(sizeof (*probability) * number_desired);
```

Doing that in a function with a passed argument will be

```
 void some_function_to_malloc(float (**probability)[4])
 {
      *probability = malloc(sizeof(**probability) * number_desired);
 }
```

Don't forget to `#include <stdlib.h>` in order to use `malloc()`.

Comment: if you do this, probability[i][j] "probably" won't do what you want

Comment: I dont know i use probability[i][j] have no problem, i dont understand what you say, can you say it more clear ? Or give me some example

Answer (score 0):

A complete example would be

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void malloc_fn(float (**x)[4]){
*x=malloc(sizeof((**x))); // allocating for one int[4]
}
int main(void)
{
int i;
float (*probability)[4];
malloc_fn(&probability);
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    (*probability)[i]=i; 
    // As pointers support array-style dereferencing,
    // (*(probability+0))[i] is equivalent to probability[0][i]
    // Note we have only allocated memory for one int[4] in our function
    // So probability[1] points to another int[4], which we have not allocated.
    // (*probability)[i]=i; is equivalent to probability[0][i]=i, See printf
}
printf("Printing the array\n");
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    printf("%f\n",probability[0][i]); // Equivalent to (*probability)[i]
}
return 0;
}
```