# How to create dynamic sized array of struct as parameter of multithread function in C

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I want to fill 2d array of struct with all 0. Firstly, I defined size of 2d array with **define** macro. As follows:

> #define VECLEN 4

I have struct as follows:

```
struct args
{
  int size;
  int array[VECLEN][VECLEN];
};
```

However, I want to get the size of my 2d array from user but I couldn't dynamically give the size of 2d array.

I use multithread functionality with **pthread_create** using 2 threads. I have to call fill function twice with multithread. When I fill the input array with defined size(4), I can easily get desired output as follows:

```
 0       0       0       0
 0       0       0       0
 0       0       0       0
 0       0       0       0
```

However, I got weird result, when I want to fill 6*6 array as follows:

```
     0       0       0       0       0       0
     0       0       0       0       0       0
     0       0       0       0       0       0
     0       0       0       0       0       0
     0       0       0       154148873       537473056       824183088
     537473056       825636144       892483616       825635638       537474100
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define VECLEN 4
pthread_mutex_t myMutex;

struct args
{
  int size;
  int array[VECLEN][VECLEN];
};

void fill(void *input)
{
   int size = ((struct args *)input)->size;

   for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
        ((struct args *)input)->array[i][j] = 0;
      }
   }
}

int main()
{
  struct args *arguments = (struct args *)malloc(sizeof(struct args));
  int number;
  printf("please enter the size : ");
  scanf("%d", &number);
  arguments->size = number;

  pthread_t threads[2];

  pthread_mutex_init(&myMutex, NULL);

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, fill, (void *)arguments);

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

  pthread_mutex_destroy(&myMutex);

  for (int row = 0; row < number; ++row)
  {
    for (int col = 0; col < number; ++col)
        printf("\t %d", arguments->array[row][col]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: `size` has to be less than or equal to `VECLEN`, otherwise you access outside the array.

Comment: You can't put a variable-length array in a structure. You should change the structure to hold a pointer to a dynamically-allocated array.

Comment: Your title says "array of struct". You don't have an array of struct, you have an array as a member of the struct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47746099/how-to-malloc-free-a-struct-with-a-contained-2d-array (classic) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448844/how-to-malloc-array-2d-in-c (current best practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `malloc` and Variably Modified types as follows (if you support C99 or above but I've also shown below the alternatives as well):

The issue with your code is that you are not allocating enough storage and additionally your array type (specifically the first dimension) is fixed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t myMutex;

struct args
{
  int size;
  int array[];
};

void fill(void *input)
{
   int size = ((struct args *)input)->size;

   int (*parray)[size] = ((struct args *)input)->array;

   for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
        parray[i][j] = 0;
      }
   }
}

int main()
{
  struct args *arguments;
  int number;
  printf("please enter the size : ");
  scanf("%d", &number);
  arguments = malloc(sizeof(struct args) + sizeof(int[number][number]));
  arguments->size = number;

  pthread_t threads[2];

  pthread_mutex_init(&myMutex, NULL);

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, fill, (void *)arguments);

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

  pthread_mutex_destroy(&myMutex);

  int (*parray)[number] = arguments->array;

  for (int row = 0; row < number; ++row)
  {
    for (int col = 0; col < number; ++col)
        printf("\t %d", parray[row][col]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Variably Modified type dimensions are calculated at runtime. We also use a flexible array member at the end of the structure and add the size of our variably modified array to the malloc call.

The benefit of this approach is that the `fill` function works as expected without modification. The alternative implementation is as follows:

```
void fill(void *input)
{
   int size = ((struct args *)input)->size;

   for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      {
        ((struct args *)input)->array[i * size + j] = 0;
      }
   }
}
```

As well as the malloc call:

```
  arguments = malloc(sizeof(struct args) + sizeof(int) * number * number);
```

For the flexible array member - the alternative approach would be:

```
struct args
{
  int size;
  int array[1];
};
```

With the following malloc:

```
  arguments = malloc(offsetof(struct args, array) + sizeof(int) * number * number);
```

The above is because of alignment issues present otherwise.

Comment: if it's not clear - my first solution uses aforementioned construct - I just gave alternatives after it - including a solution without Flexible member whilst the quoted piece of code is solely demonstrating that Variably modified types can be substituted with a calculation of `sizeof(int)` multiplied by `number` 2 times (and it still assumes the first solution is used - which if you had looked closely uses FMA). Also if you knew how to read - it would helped substantially as well - "For the flexible array member - **the alternative approach would be**:".

Comment: BTW, good use of `sizeof(int) * number * number` and not `number * number * sizeof(int)`.    The 2nd may overflow where the first does not.