# Multiplying Quadratic Matrices Using Pointers In C

Tags: c, pointers

I have a task where I'm supposed to multiply two quadratic matrices of size `n` in C, using pointers as function parameters and return value. This is the given function head: `int** multiply(int** a, int** b, int n)`. Normally, I would use three arrays (the two matrices and the result) as parameters, but since I had to do it this way, this is what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int** multiply(int** a, int** b, int n) {
  int **c = malloc(sizeof(int) * n * n);
  // Rows of c
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // Columns of c
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      // c[i][j] = Row of a * Column of b
      for (int k = 0; i < n; k++) {
        *(*(c + i) + j) += *(*(a + i) + k) * *(*(b + k) + j);
      }
    }
  }
  return c;
}

int main() {
  int **a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2 * 2);
  int **b = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2 * 2);

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < 2; j++) {
      *(*(a + i) + j) = i - j;
      *(*(b + i) + j) = j - i;
    }
  }
  
  int **c = multiply(a, b, 2);

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      printf("c[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, c[i][j]);
    }
  }

  free(a);
  free(b);
  free(c);

  return 0;
}
```

I have not worked much with pointers before, and am generally new to C, so I have no idea why this doesn't work or what I'd have to do instead. The error I'm getting when trying to run this program is `segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I don't even know exactly what that means... :(

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: There are a few ways to create a 2d matrix in C. In one method you allocate a 1d block of memory and calculate the row/col by converting to an index.  Another way is to create an array of pointers then allocate each row. You seem to be mixing the 2. See also: [Freaky way of allocating two-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36794202)

Comment: `int **c = malloc(sizeof(int) * n * n);` is wrong and will not work. Do not use a pointer to a pointer to represent a matrix. I recommend using `int*` and doing index calculations manually, i.,e. `int* c = malloc(n*n*sizeof(int)); ...; c[i*n+j] = ....;` Do not use `*(c + i)` to index into an array, `c[i]` means exactly the same thing and is easier to read.

Comment: Do not "fix" your question once there are answers posted! That renders answers obsolete or nonsensical, and future readers won't understand a thing of the whole post. I'll rollback edits.

Comment: @Lundin Okay, sorry. Could you still help me out and tell me how this would work with the new function header?

Comment: Depends on if you want to become a good C programmer or if you just want to please your incompetent teacher... In case it's the latter, someone posted a different answer about that.

Answer (score 4):

There's lots of fundamental problems in the code. Most notably, `int**` is not a 2D array and cannot point at one.

- `i<2` typo in the `for(int j...` loop.
- `i < n` in the `for(int k...` loop.
- To allocate a 2D array you must do: `int (*a)[2] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2 * 2);`. Or if you will `malloc( sizeof(int[2][2]) )`, same thing.
- To access a 2D array you do `a[i][j]`.
- To pass a 2D array to a function you do `void func (int n, int arr[n][n]);`
- Returning a 2D array from a function is trickier, easiest for now is just to use `void*` and get that working.
- `malloc` doesn't initialize the allocated memory. If you want to do `+=` on `c` you should use `calloc` instead, to set everything to zero.
- Don't write an unreadable mess like `*(*(c + i) + j)`. Write `c[i][j]`.

I fixed these problems and got something that runs. You check if the algorithm is correct from there.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* multiply(int n, int a[n][n], int b[n][n]) {
  int (*c)[n] = calloc(1, sizeof(int[n][n]));

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
      }
    }
  }
  return c;
}

int main() {
  int (*a)[2] = malloc(sizeof(int[2][2]));
  int (*b)[2] = malloc(sizeof(int[2][2]));

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      a[i][j] = i - j;
      b[i][j] = j - i;
    }
  }
  
  int (*c)[2] = multiply(2, a, b);

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      printf("c[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, c[i][j]);
    }
  }

  free(a);
  free(b);
  free(c);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. There is just one problem: The function header I gave in my question is given in the task and is what we're supposed to use, so I can't just change the function to have two arrays as parameters instead of pointers. It has to be `int* multiply(int* a, int* b, int n)`

Comment: @RalphBear Then give the link [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) to your teacher so that they may learn how to program correctly in C. It is particularly directed to incompetent teachers. The `int**` misconception is incredibly common.

Comment: @Ludin I already fixed my mistake: It's pointers, not pointers to pointers. Just one `*` everywhere. That's what's given for the function header. `int* multiply(int* a, int* b, int n)`

Comment: @RalphBear That doesn't make much sense unless you calculate the indices manually too. You can no longer use `arr[i][j]` if you use `int*`. Nor can you use the pointer arithmetic present in the function.

Comment: @Lundin That is why I came here in the first place. I was given this task which says to use pointers (see the corrected function header that I meationed a few times already) and have no idea how to make this work when I'm not allowed to just use arrays.

Comment: @RalphBear Since arrays "decay" into pointers to their first element whenever used as function parameters, `a` and `b` in `multiply(int n, int a[n][n], int b[n][n])` _are_ actually pointers. You could as well have declared the parameter as `int (*a)[n]` and it would have been 100% equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix multiple errors here:

1/ line 5/24/28: `int **c = malloc(sizeof(int*) * n )`

2/ line 15: `k<n`

3/ Remark: use `a[i][j]` instead of `*(*(a+i)+j)`

4/ line 34: `j<2`

5/ check how to create a 2d matrix using pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
  
int** multiply(int** a, int** b, int n) {
  int **c = malloc(sizeof(int*) * n );
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    c[i]=malloc(sizeof(int) * n );
  }
  
  // Rows of c
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // Columns of c
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      // c[i][j] = Row of a * Column of b
      for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
      }
    }
  }
  return c;
}

int main() {
  int **a = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 2);
  for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
    a[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
  }
  int **b = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
  for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
    b[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      a[i][j] = i - j;
      b[i][j] = i - j;
    }
  }

  int **c = multiply(a, b, 2); 

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) { 
      printf("c[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, c[i][j]); 
    } 
  } 
  free(a);
  free(b);
  free(c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't create 2D arrays though. It is needlessly slow and needlessly complex. See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Answer (score 1):

From the updated requirement, the actual function prototype is `int *multiply(int *a, int *b, int n);` so the code should use a "flattened" matrix representation consisting of a 1-D array of length `n * n`.

Using a flattened representation, element (`i`, `j`) of the `n * n` matrix `m` is accessed as `m[i * n + j]` or equivalently using the unary `*` operator as `*(m + i * n + j)`. (I think the array indexing operators are more readable.)

First, let us fix some errors in the `for` loop variables. In `multiply`:

```
      for (int k = 0; i < n; k++) {
```

should be:

```
      for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
```

In `main`:

```
    for (int j = 0; i < 2; j++) {
```

should be:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
```

The original code has a loop that sums the terms for each element of the resulting matrix `c`, but is missing the initialization of the element to 0 before the summation.

Corrected code, using the updated prototype with flattened matrix representation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* multiply(int* a, int* b, int n) {
  int *c = malloc(sizeof(int) * n * n);
  // Rows of c
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // Columns of c
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      // c[i][j] = Row of a * Column of b
      c[i * n + j] = 0;
      for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        c[i * n + j] += a[i * n + k] * b[k * n + j];
      }
    }
  }
  return c;
}

int main() {
  int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2 * 2);
  int *b = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2 * 2);

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      a[i * 2 + j] = i - j;
      b[i * 2 + j] = j - i;
    }
  }
  
  int *c = multiply(a, b, 2);

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      printf("c[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, c[i * 2 + j]);
    }
  }

  free(a);
  free(b);
  free(c);

  return 0;
}
```