# What is "int (*arr)[cols]" where "cols" is a variable, in C++?

Tags: c++, c, variable-length-array

I am reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36794202/4366445) to consider about how to dynamically allocate memory for a two-dimensional array.

I notice that a variable value `cols` can be used as size to define `int (*arr)[cols]`, as `C` language has variable-length arrays(VLA) feature, then I try modifying the code into `C++` like:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

void* allocate(size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    int (*arr)[cols] = (int (*)[cols])malloc(rows *sizeof(*arr));
    memset(arr, 0, rows *sizeof(*arr));
    return arr;
}

int main() {
    size_t rows, cols;
    scanf("%zu %zu", &rows, &cols);

    int (*arr)[cols] = (int (*)[cols])allocate(rows, cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf("%3d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

[compile with `gcc 11.2 -std=c++11`](https://godbolt.org/z/7c5coKdch)

To my surprise, this works well and compiler does not report any warning. AFAIK `C++` [has no VLA feature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array), I used to think this code should be forbidden. So why could this work?

Comment: It is indeed not standard C++, some compilers allow it as an extension.

Comment: It's a diagnosable error in standard C++.    g++ supports VLAs as a non-standard extension by default.    Turn up the warning/error levels to get a diagnostic about VLAs.

Comment: If you program in C++, may I ask why you use `scanf` and `printf` instead of the standard C++ streams `std::cin` and `std::cout`? If the shown code is copied from somewhere else, are you sure it's from a C++ program and not a C program originally? The only C++ specific parts of the code are those header files, nothing else. I think that whatever resource you got the code from, don't use it as a reference or learning resource for C++.

Comment: Add `-pedantic-errors` flag to get an error.

Comment: @Peter I did compile with option `-std=c++11`, should the g++ extension be disabled?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The original code is in `C`, I only modify some specific parts such as headers and type cast in front of `malloc`, in fact I concern about the difference between `C` and `C++`, originally I want to verify that VLA is not supported by `C++` so this pattern to allocate dynamic 2-dim array maybe quite limited. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: `-std=c++11` simply specifies a dialect.   You *also* need to enable options that make `g++` more picky with warnings and to treat warnings as errors.   `-pedantic-errors` is the minimum, but I also turn on `-Wall -Weffc++ -Wextra` and a few others, as well as enabling `-Werror` (which treats warnings as errors).   Essentially, if a compiler *can* complain about something, I want it, and I aim to build without warnings or errors (on multiple compilers where practical).

Comment: Set the compiler flags for C++ Standard conformance - live - https://godbolt.org/z/bbEoT7W3e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-std=c++11` doesn't mean "compile strictly according to C++11" but "enable C++11 features." Just as `-std=gnu++11` (the default setting) means enable gnu++11 features, which is a superset of C++11.

To get strictly compliant behavior, you must use `-std=c++11 -pedantic-errors`. And then you get this:

> `error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'arr' [-Wvla]`

See [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565) for details. It was written for C but applies identically to g++ as well.