# Code for creating a Rotation Table working in GDB online, but not working in Code::Blocks

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, dynamic

I want to start by saying that I'm absolutely not an expert with C programming and I haven't done it in a while.

But I was tasked with writing code in C for a problem regarding combinatorics.

The basic task is, given any word, to construct a square table containing all possible right shifts of a word. There's also a lot of stuff after this first step, but this is the most important one and the one that's giving me trouble.

Pratical example:
If the word is "ababa", the "2D array" should contain:

1. ababa
2. aabab
3. baaba
4. abaab
5. babaa

Since this 2D array is always length * length in size (so if the word has length 5, the table will be 5x5) I thought the thing to do was:

1. Calling a function passing the length as a parameter
2. Create a char** with malloc so it is the correct size
3. return said char**
4. Calling another function to fill it with the strings

I came up with the following code, but while it is actually perfectly working in GDB online, it returns an error in Code::Blocks. The error is: **Process terminated with status -1073741819**

What baffles me is that, when I try to debug it, inside Code::Blocks the code actually works.
This is the function that allocates the array:

```
char** returnTable(int length){
char** rotationTable = malloc(length*sizeof(char));
char* values = calloc((length+1)*(length+1), sizeof(char));

for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        rotationTable[i] = values + i*(length+1);
        rotationTable[i][0] = '\0';
}
return rotationTable;}
```

And this is the function that fills the struct with the right words:

```
void orderedConjugacyClass(char** table, char* word, int length){
    //first word copied in the rotationTable
    table[0] = strdup(word);
    //let's start from the second row
    int j = 1;
    //p on the last char of the word
    char* p = &table[j-1][length-1];
    //q on the first 
    char* q = &table[j-1][0];
    //buffer string, +1 for terminating character
    char buffer[length+1];
    buffer[0] = '\0';

    while(j < length){
        strncat(buffer, p, 1);
        strncat(buffer, q, length-1);
        buffer[length] = '\0';
        table[j] = strdup(buffer);
        p = &table[j][length-1];
        q = &table[j][0];
        //to cancel and reuse the buffer for next iteration
        buffer[0]='\0';
        j++;
    }
}
```

In the main I simply call both functions. And If I just limit myself to that, the code doesn't (apparently) have problems. But whenever I try to access the contents of the table and display it with a printf, that's when the problem occurs and the output "diverges" between GDB online and CodeBlocks:

```
 int length = strlen(argv[1]);
        char** rotationTable = returnTable(length);
        orderedConjugacyClass(rotationTable, argv[1], length);
        
        for(int j=0; j<length; j++)
                printf("%s\n", rotationTable[j]);
        
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
            free(rotationTable[i]);
        free(rotationTable);
        return 0;
```

Additional Details: I'm on Windows, MinGW compiler.

Thank you for your help and understanding.

Comment: You are not allocating the arrays properly.  [Allocate memory 2d array in function C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15062765) and [Freaky way of allocating two-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36794369)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
SomeType something = malloc(length*sizeof(SomeType));
```

Do this:

```
SomeType something = malloc(length*sizeof(*something));
```

The first one is only correct if the two uses of `SomeType` are identical, and it's a very easy mistake to make them different, particularly if you change `SomeType` at some point in your program development.

In this case, you wrote

```
char** rotationTable = malloc(length*sizeof(char));
```

Here, the element type is `char*` but you used `char` in the `sizeof`, which lead to you allocating too little space.

If you'd written

```
char** rotationTable = malloc(length*sizeof(*rotationTable));
```

you wouldn't have had that problem.

---

Also note that you're preallocating the elements of `rotationTable` and then replacing the preallocated arrays with other arrays. The originally allocated pointers are lost, so you never free them, so you have a memory leak. I don't see the point of `returnTable`. Just have `orderedConjugacyClass` create and return the array.

---

Finally, this is silly.

```
        strncat(buffer, p, 1);
        strncat(buffer, q, length-1);
        buffer[length] = '\0';
```

`strncat` has to scan the destination to find its end. But you know where the end is. So the cycles spent scanning the string are completely pointless.

```
buffer[0] = p[0];
memcpy(buffer+1, q, length-1);
buffer[length] = '\0';
```

On the other hand, `p` and `q` are kind of pointless as well, since you could just copy from the original word. Indeed, you could get rid of `buffer` as well:

```
/* Production code should check if malloc succeeded */
char** conjTable(const char* word) {
    size_t len = strlen(word);
    char** table = malloc(len * sizeof(*table));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        table[i] = malloc(len + 1);
        memcpy(table[i], word + len - i, i);
        memcpy(table[i] + i, word, len - i);
        table[i][len] = '\0';
    }
    return table;
}
```