# Return type of function for this odd way of creating 2D array

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

Source reference for this question: [Freaky way of allocating 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36794202/645128)

I have used an an adaptation of the code shown in the answers of the referenced post to create an array of strings:

```
char (*string)[rows] = malloc(sizeof(char [rows][cols]));
memset(string, 0, sizeof(char [rows][cols]));
```

I realize that for extremely large arrays, this method would not be optimal as a single large block of contiguous memory becomes very expensive when attempting to allocate.  But when creating small to medium sized arrays, the advantages can be attractive.  Eg. This method uses only a single call to `malloc()`, to allocate a single contiguous block memory, therefore requires only one call to `free()` when done using it,  making it a desirable alternative to more idiomatic methods I have seen. (those using multiple calls to `malloc()` and `free()`,)

So, I would like to encapsulate it into a function, but thus far I have not discovered what return type is compatible:

```
T  CreateStringArray(int rows, int cols)
{
    char (*string)[rows] = malloc(sizeof(char [rows][cols]));
    memset(string, 0, sizeof(char [rows][cols]));

    return T;
}
```

What form of `T` would work with this function?

Comment: <O/T> suggest `calloc` vs `malloc; memset`

Comment: Why do you need to do it this way? I'm pretty sure this wont work either because of how the stack works. Just do ```char ** string = malloc(...)```. Not trying to bikeshed your code, just a suggestion.

Comment: @squidwardsface - if you are suggesting what I think you are, multiple calls to `malloc()/free()`` would be required, each writing to a fresh memory location, and taking much more time to do it.   If this is not what you are suggesting, please clarify.

Comment: How a bunch of small allocations is going to be cheaper than the single one?

Comment: @tstanisl - question address to me?  (if so, the answer is _more_ allocations are _more_ costly.)

Comment: but the question suggests that "for extremely large arrays, this method would not be optimal". Could you elaborate why? Is there any better alternative?

Comment: @tstanisl - I think I confused the issue a little bit by my last comment to you.  On the one side, although a single call to `[m][c]alloc()` is quick, and freeing is easier, for really large amounts of contiguous memory it can be difficult to impossible for the OS to provide.  i.e. it will return NULL. (expensive)  For a bunch of calls, each asking for smaller segments of memory, each of which is part of an idiomatic implementation of a dynamically allocated 2D  array, the expense is not to the OS, it is to the code,in that a bunch of smaller segments need to be managed, i.e. created and freed

Comment: @ryyker I just wrote a program that creates a bunch of garbage, then performs 2,000,000 mallocs and frees of random sizes between 1 and 2^16. It was compiled with -O0 to ensure no compiler optimizations. It took 3 seconds to execute on my crappy old lenovo. Unless you're going to be creating hundreds of thousands of huge string arrays and also require real-time execution of your program, you don't need to worry about performance impacts of malloc/free.

Comment: Also, why not just do something like ```char * strings = malloc(rows * cols)``` and then do ```&strings[cols * i]``` to extract the i'th string? As long as you trust yourself to write correct code, this approach should work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would *like* to return `char (*)[rows]`, but this is a variably-modified type, and only objects (not functions) declared with no linkage (unlike all functions) at block or function prototype scope can have variably-modified types (C17 6.7.6.2/2).

Therefore, the best you can do for the return type of of your function is `char *` or `void *`.

However, you could patch that up with a macro:

```
void *CreateStringArray_func(int rows, int cols)
{
    char (*string)[rows] = malloc(sizeof(char [rows][cols]));
    memset(string, 0, sizeof(char [rows][cols]));

    return string;
}

#define CreateStringArray(rows, cols) \
    ((char (*)[rows]) CreateStringArray_func(rows, cols))
```

But in that particular case, I would probably just use

```
#define CreateStringArray(rows, cols) calloc(rows, cols)
```

You can add the cast to the latter, too, but I omit it on the principle of not casting the result of allocation functions.

Comment: So, with your first example a call would be made as `char (*string)[3] = CreateStringArray(3,4);  If(string){//continue}` ?

Comment: Yes, @rykker, just so.  Well, lowercase `if`.

Comment: LOL, yes.  Typo on the `if`.  But works as you described.   Thanks.  This is a workable approach.  Interesting side affect on this array creation method in general.  When attempting to view memory contents in debug environment, I can see only the first byte  of each array element.  Probably because elements are in the form `(*p)[n]`.  With the more idiomatic way of creating 2D string array, I can see entire string for each location.

Comment: In all other answers, there is a distinction pointing out that the return type should be `char (*p)[col]` as opposed to `char (*p)[row]`.  Should `char (*p)[col]` be used in yours as well?

Comment: @ryyker, if the implementation is to be consistent with the `CreateStringArray()` function given in the question, then the correct pointer type for the allocation within and for the function's return is `char (*)[rows]`, as specified in this answer.  Alaa's answer changes the semantics of the function in a consistent way.  Vlad's return type is inconsistent with the pointer type used internally.  `char (*)[col]` is probably what you actually want, and if done right then the allocation size is the same either way, but of these, only the typing presented here answers the question as posed.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like that:

```
void * CreateStringArray(int rows, int cols)
{
    char (*string)[cols] = malloc(sizeof(char [rows][cols]));
    memset((void*)string, 0, sizeof(char [rows][cols]));

    return string;
}

int main()
{
    char (*p)[4] = (char (*)[4])CreateStringArray(3, 4);
}
```

Note that `char (*string)[cols]` shall be defined with `cols` not `rows`. because `string` is a pointer to a one-dimensional array of `cols` elements.

**Extension:**

Details on why use `cols` instead of `rows`:

An array name, when used, is a pointer to its first element. For example `int arr[5]`, here `arr` is a pointer to `a[0]`.

Though `int a[rows][cols]`, here `a` is not apointer to `a[0][0]` instead it is a pointer to its `a[0]` which has the type `int (*)[cols]`

To understand that, you have to think about how C is storing a multi-dimensional array in the memory? it's actually stored as a one-dimensional array row by row.

e.g. `int a[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};` is stored as `1 2 3 4 5 6`, here `a[0]`is `{1, 2, 3}` so a pointer to `a[0]` is apointer to `{1, 2, 3}` which is a pointer to an array of 3 integers which can be written as `int (*)[3]` => ingeneral it's `int (*) [cols]'

Comment: Minor nitpicking. Don't cast to `void*`, its pointless for memset

Comment: I'm an Embedded SW engineer so I'm used to explicit casting to avoid any MISRA warnings. none of the casts are necessary actually because the compiler is making implicit cast anyway.

Comment: I am unclear why you appear to be choosing to reverse the `row/col` reference.  I seem to be able to use your method except using `char (*p)[row]... char [row][col]`.  Maybe I am invoking UB?  Can you expand a little more why you feel it is important to do this?

Comment: The allocation and initialization code could be compressed to simple `calloc(rows, sizeof *string)`

Comment: @ryyker The answer extended to shed more light on pointers and multi-dimentional arrays

Comment: @tstanisl correct!

Comment: Btw.. afaik MISRA forbids implicit casting **from** void, not **to** void

Comment: Thanks for the additional information.  I had finally got it a few minutes ago when testing your answer.  Works great btw, thank you.  My usage includes dropping the cast to the function as it is `void *`.  `char (*p)[4] = CreateStringArray(3, 4);`.

Comment: @tstanisl: Correct!

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood correctly the function should return the allocated pointer within the function,

The pointer has the type `char (*)[cols]`  but when the function is declared the return type of the function knows nothing about the variable cols.

In this case the function should be declared like

```
void * CreateStringArray(int rows, int cols) )
{
    char (*string)[rows] = malloc(sizeof(char [rows][cols]));
    memset(string, 0, sizeof(char [rows][cols]));

    return string;
}
```

And in the caller you can write

```
char ( *string )[cols] = CreateStringArray( rows, cols );
```