# Mallocing int* inside of int** gives unexpected integer values in the first and sometimes second allocation

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I am having this problem. Basically I want to parse an integer string to an int** where the sub int arrays are two long. The first index is the digit and the second is the power of ten associated to the digit.

For example 12345 would give [[1, 4], [2, 3], [3, 2], [4, 1], [5, 0]]

Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

int    ft_strlen(char *str)
{
    int    count;

    count = 0;
    while (*str++)
        count++;
    return (count);
}

int **parray(char *str)
{
    int **ret;
    int len;
    int i;

    len = ft_strlen(str);
    ret = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int) * len);
    if (ret == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    i = 0;
    while (i < len)
    {
        ret[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
        if (ret[i] == NULL)
            return (NULL);
        ret[i][0] = str[i] - '0';
        ret[i][1] = len - 1 - i;
        i++;
    }
    return (ret);
}
```

This then get tested in a main function as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "1255555555555555";
    int**ret = parray(str);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < ft_strlen(str))
    {
        printf("%d ", ret[i][0]);
        printf("%d ", ret[i][1]);
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }
}
```

This for some reason prints out:

```
29791280 0 
29791408 0 
5 13 
5 12 
5 11 
5 10 
5 9 
5 8 
5 7 
5 6 
5 5 
5 4 
5 3 
5 2 
5 1 
5 0
```

Note that the program works fine with strings less or equal to 4 digits. The first two non working values also always change when u run the program again. Im assuimng there is some overflow somewhere but I don't know where, nor how. Im fairly new to c so please excuse me if this is a silly mistake.

Comment: Looks more like c than c++, Only tag the language in which the code is written in. C and C++ are different languages. **In c++, don't write code like this.**

Comment: this will make more sense if you use (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*len)

Comment: Do you *have* to do it this way?  Just to start, you're storing a lot of redundant information.  In particular, the power of ten in each small array is a function only of that array's position in the larger array and the total number of digits.

Comment: `char *str = "1255555555555555";` -- This is not C++.  String literals in C++ are `const char *`.

Comment: And if you insist on that redundancy, then do you really need pointer-to-pointer structure instead of a bona fide 2D array?

Comment: Why not `struct digit_info { int digit; int power; };` and create a dynamic array of `digit_info`?

Comment: Minor point: `printf` can print multiple values. Those three output statements would usually be written as a single call: `printf("%d %d\n", ret[i][0], ret[i][1]);`.

Comment: _Side note:_ Get in the habit of calling `free` to dispose of any allocation made with `malloc`. Sure. In this case, the system will clean up the free store when function `main` ends, but my choice would be to do it myself. It's my habit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ret = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int) * len);` is wrong. The type of `ret` is `int **`. It is a pointer to `int *`. You are allocating space for `int *`. So you want the size of `int *`.

Generally, it is preferable to calculate the size from the thing you are assigning to:

```
ret = malloc(len * sizeof *ret);`
```

`*ret` is a sample of what `ret` will point to, so `sizeof *ret` is the size of one of those things. In this case, it will be the size of an `int *`. This form automatically adjusts the allocation size to whatever type `ret` is. For example, if you change the declaration of `ret` later, while working on your program, the size here will automatically be correct without needing another edit.

Also, do not cast the return value of `malloc` in C. (C++ is different.) There is no need for it, and it can mask a failure to declare `malloc` (because an include of a header was accidentally omitted).

Answer (score 1):

Coding a two-dimensional, dynamically allocated array of `int` is a non-trivial task. If you use a *double pointer*, there are significant memory allocation details. In particular, you need to check every allocation attempt, and, if any one fails, back out of the ones that didn't fail, without leaking memory. And, finally, to take a term from the C++ lexicon, you need to provide some equivalent of the *Rule of Three* functions used by a C++ *RAII* class.

A two-dimensional array of `int` with `n_rows` and `n_cols` should probably be allocated with a single call to `malloc`. For the program in the OP, you might have:

```c
char *str = "1255555555555555";
const size_t n_rows = strlen(str);
const size_t n_cols = 2;
int (*data)[n_cols] = malloc(n_rows * sizeof (*data));
```

Variable `data` is a *pointer to an array of 2 `int`s*, i.e., it is a pointer to a row in the OP's two-dimensional array. `sizeof(*data)`, therefore, is the size of one row. Multiplying by `n_rows` gives you the size of the entire array, which is the size allocated by `malloc`. So, `malloc` allocates the entire array, and variable `data` picks up a pointer to the first row.

See this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36794202/22193627) for a fuller explanation of this C idiom. Also, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

The program in the OP, however, does not use this idiom. It takes the *double pointer* route, and allocates an *array of pointers to int*. The elements in such an array are `int*`. Thus, the array is an *array of pointers to rows*, where each row is an *array of `int`*. The argument to the `sizeof` operator, therefore, must be `int*`.

```c
int** data = malloc(n_rows * sizeof (int*));  // step 1.
```

Afterwards, you run a loop to allocate the columns of each row. Conceptually, each row is an array of `int`, with `malloc` returning a pointer to the first element of each row.

```c
for (size_t r = 0; r < n_rows; ++r)
    data[r] = malloc(n_cols * sizeof int);  // step 2.
```

The program in the OP errs in step 1.

```c
// from the OP:
ret = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int) * len);  // should be sizeof(int*)
```

Taking guidance from the [answer by @Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78248309/22193627), this can be coded as:

```c
int** ret = malloc(len * sizeof *ret);
```

The program below, however, uses (the equivalent of):

```c
int** ret = malloc(len * sizeof(int*));
```

##### Fixing memory leaks

The program in the OP is careful to check each call to `malloc`, and abort the allocation process if any one of them fails. After a failure, however, it does not call `free` to release the allocations that were successful. Potentially, therefore, it leaks memory. It should keep track of the row where a failure occurs, and call `free` on the preceding rows. It should also call `free` on the original array of pointers.

There is enough detail to warrant refactoring the code to create a separate header with functions to manage a two-dimensional array. This separates the business of array management from the application itself.

Header `tbx.int_array2D.h`, defined below, provides the following functions.

- *Struct* – `struct int_array2D_t` holds a `data` pointer, along with variables for `n_rows` and `n_cols`.
- *Make* – Function `make_int_array2D` handles allocations, and returns a `struct int_array2D_t` object.
- *Free* – Function `free_int_array2D` handles deallocations.
- *Clone* – Function `clone_int_array2D` returns a *deep copy* of a `struct int_array2D_t` object. It can be used in initialization expressions, but, in general, should not be used for assignments.
- *Swap* – Function `swap_int_array2D` swaps two `int_array2D_t` objects.
- *Copy assign* – Function `copy_assign_int_array2D` replaces an existing `int_array2D_t` object with a *deep copy* of another. It performs allocation and deallocation, as needed.
- *Move assign* – Function `move_assign_int_array2D` deallocates an existing `int_array2D_t` object, and replaces it with a *shallow copy* of another. After assignment, it zeros-out the source.
- *Equals* – Function `equals_int_array2D` performs a *deep comparison* of two `int_array2D_t` objects, returning `1` when they are equal, and `0`, otherwise.

```c
#pragma once
// tbx.int_array2D.h
#include <stddef.h>

struct int_array2D_t
{
    int** data;
    size_t n_rows;
    size_t n_cols;
};
void free_int_array2D(
    struct int_array2D_t* a);

struct int_array2D_t make_int_array2D(
    const size_t n_rows, 
    const size_t n_cols);

struct int_array2D_t clone_int_array2D(
    const struct int_array2D_t* a);

void swap_int_array2D(
    struct int_array2D_t* a,
    struct int_array2D_t* b);

void copy_assign_int_array2D(
    struct int_array2D_t* a,
    const struct int_array2D_t* b);

void move_assign_int_array2D(
    struct int_array2D_t* a,
    struct int_array2D_t* b);

int equals_int_array2D(
    const struct int_array2D_t* a, 
    const struct int_array2D_t* b);

// end file: tbx.int_array2D.h
```

##### A trivial application

With these functions, code for the application becomes almost trivial.

I am not sure why the OP wrote his own version of `strlen`, but I went with it, changing only the type of its return value.

```c
// main.c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tbx.int_array2D.h"

size_t ft_strlen(char* str)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    while (*str++)
        count++;
    return (count);
}

struct int_array2D_t parray(char* str)
{
    size_t len = ft_strlen(str);
    struct int_array2D_t ret = make_int_array2D(len, 2);
    for (size_t r = ret.n_rows; r--;) {
        ret.data[r][0] = str[r] - '0';
        ret.data[r][1] = (int)(len - 1 - r);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    char* str = "1255555555555555";
    struct int_array2D_t ret = parray(str);
    for (size_t r = 0; r < ret.n_rows; ++r) {
        printf("%d %d \n", ret.data[r][0], ret.data[r][1]);
    }
    free_int_array2D(&ret);
}
// end file: main.c
```

##### Source code for `tbx.int_array2D.c`

Function `free_int_array2D` has been designed so that it can be used for the normal deallocation of an array, such as happens in function `main`, and also so that it can be called from function `make_int_array2D`, when an allocation fails.

Either way, it sets the `data` pointer to `NULL`, and both `n_rows` and `n_cols` to zero. Applications that use header `tbx.int_array2D.h` can check the `data` pointer of objects returned by functions `make_int_array2D`, `clone_int_array2D`, and `copy_assign_int_array2D`. If it is `NULL`, then the allocation failed.

```c
// tbx.int_array2D.c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tbx.int_array2D.h"

//======================================================================
// free_int_array2D
//======================================================================
void free_int_array2D(struct int_array2D_t* a)
{
    for (size_t r = a->n_rows; r--;)
        free(a->data[r]);
    free(a->data);
    a->data = NULL;
    a->n_rows = 0;
    a->n_cols = 0;
}
//======================================================================
// make_int_array2D
//======================================================================
struct int_array2D_t make_int_array2D(
    const size_t n_rows, 
    const size_t n_cols)
{
    struct int_array2D_t a = {
        malloc(n_rows * sizeof(int*)),
        n_rows,
        n_cols
    };
    if (!n_rows || !n_cols)
    {
        // If size is zero, the behavior of malloc is implementation-
        // defined. For example, a null pointer may be returned. 
        // Alternatively, a non-null pointer may be returned; but such 
        // a pointer should not be dereferenced, and should be passed 
        // to free to avoid memory leaks. – CppReference
        // https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc

        free(a.data);
        a.data = NULL;
        a.n_rows = 0;
        a.n_cols = 0;
    }
    else if (a.data == NULL) {
        a.n_rows = 0;
        a.n_cols = 0;
    }
    else {
        for (size_t r = 0; r < n_rows; ++r) {
            a.data[r] = malloc(n_cols * sizeof(int));
            if (a.data[r] == NULL) {
                a.n_rows = r;
                free_int_array2D(&a);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}
//======================================================================
// clone_int_array2D
//======================================================================
struct int_array2D_t clone_int_array2D(const struct int_array2D_t* a)
{
    struct int_array2D_t clone = make_int_array2D(a->n_rows, a->n_cols);
    for (size_t r = clone.n_rows; r--;) {
        for (size_t c = clone.n_cols; c--;) {
            clone.data[r][c] = a->data[r][c];
        }
    }
    return clone;
}
//======================================================================
// swap_int_array2D
//======================================================================
void swap_int_array2D(
    struct int_array2D_t* a,
    struct int_array2D_t* b)
{
    struct int_array2D_t t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
//======================================================================
// copy_assign_int_array2D
//======================================================================
void copy_assign_int_array2D(
    struct int_array2D_t* a,
    const struct int_array2D_t* b)
{
    if (a->data != b->data) {
        if (a->n_rows != b->n_rows || a->n_cols != b->n_cols) {
            free_int_array2D(a);
            *a = make_int_array2D(b->n_rows, b->n_cols);
        }
        for (size_t r = a->n_rows; r--;) {
            for (size_t c = a->n_cols; c--;) {
                a->data[r][c] = b->data[r][c];
            }
        }
    }
}
//======================================================================
// move_assign_int_array2D
//======================================================================
void move_assign_int_array2D(
    struct int_array2D_t* a,
    struct int_array2D_t* b)
{
    if (a->data != b->data) {
        free_int_array2D(a);
        *a = *b;
        b->data = NULL;
        b->n_rows = 0;
        b->n_cols = 0;
    }
}
//======================================================================
// equals_int_array2D
//======================================================================
int equals_int_array2D(
    const struct int_array2D_t* a, 
    const struct int_array2D_t* b)
{
    if (a->n_rows != b->n_rows ||
        a->n_cols != b->n_cols) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (size_t r = a->n_rows; r--;) {
        for (size_t c = a->n_cols; c--;) {
            if (a->data[r][c] != b->data[r][c]) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
// end file: tbx.int_array2D.c
```